# Cast from 'NSPersistentStoreResult' to unrelated type '[entity]' always fails

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am using Core Data in my app. I am facing trouble in fetching the results back from coredata. My entity name is Wonders.

Now I managed to successfully save a record. Now when I am fetching it back I am using the following code.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let wondersAppdel:AppDelegate=UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as!AppDelegate
    let WondersContext:NSManagedObjectContext = wondersAppdel.managedObjectContext
    let wondersFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Wonders")
    wondersFetchRequest.predicate=NSPredicate(format: "wonderShow = %@", true)
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "wonderName", ascending: true)
    wondersFetchRequest.sortDescriptors=[sortDescriptor]



    do {
        if
            let wonderFetchresults = try WondersContext.executeRequest(wondersFetchRequest) as? [Wonders]{
        wonders = wonderFetchresults
        }
        else{print("else if result...try")}
    }
    catch{
        fatalError("there was an error fatching the list of gruops!")}
        self.tableview.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be calling executeFetchRequest method of NSManagedObjectContext when you are performing a NSFetchRequest.

```
try WondersContext.executeFetchRequest(wondersFetchRequest)
```

Comment: Bro can I have you in social network i interest to be familiar  and friend with you

Comment: My twitter handle is @ahmedonawale

Answer (score 2):

As of Swift 3.0, you can take advantage of the auto-generated `fetchRequest()` function on your custom `NSManagedObject` subclasses:

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<Wonders> = Wonders.fetchRequest()
let allWonders = try WondersContext.fetch(request)
```

...and there is no longer any need to cast the result as it will automatically return an array cast to the relevant class (or more accurately, an optional array of the relevant class). Predicates and sort descriptors can be added in the usual way as required, or even programmed directly into the auto-generated `fetchRequest()` function for the relevant object if there's a default you should fall back on.